# Can't update old Configurable Products after update from Magento 2.3 to Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

when I update Magento from 2.3 to 2.4.1, I can't save the old Configurable Products, it said that error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `cp_table`.`type_id` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cp_table` ON main_table.product_id = cp_table.entity_id WHERE (`main_table`.`website_id` = '0') AND (`main_table`.`product_id` IN())",

but when create a new Configurable Products, it still works perfect.

[image]

Do anyone have same problem, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you fix the error?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like an issue caused by a 3rd party extension. How do I know this? Because the *'Magento style'* aliases to tables are formatted by using the first char of the table name parts, so basically `catalog_product_entity` would be `cpe` and not `cp`.

I suggest you either disable the 3rd party modules and enable them back one by one to see which causes the problem OR install xdebug and debug the admin page to see where it gets stuck. However, depending on how your log settings, you might already have the error stack trace in the log files, so take a look there too.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try your suggest, hope I can find the problem soon. Have a nice day!

Comment: I am facing the same error as above. I have checked the Magento core code, and they are using `cp_table` for `catalog_product_entity` in `Magento/module-catalog-inventory` So, it's from core Magento and not from any 3rd party module.  Specially this two files `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Item/StockItemCriteriaMapper.php` and `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Model/ResourceModel/Stock/Status/StockStatusCriteriaMapper.php`  @chinhnguyen let me know if you are able to find any solution for this.